# Owner of folder has no permission on it

Tags: sudo, ownership

I have recently created a user who has no access to any shell commands. Problem is, this user can still `vim`, `nano` or `ls` into any file and see the content. I created a `home/username/` folder only accessible and modifiable by him. But now I can't do any modification with `sudo` because only the user has access to this folder... And of course, the user can't do modification either as he has no shell commands available to him. (except `nano`, `vi`, `vim`, `ls`...)

Do you know of any workaround? I just want the user to only be able to switch user with `su`.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: to give a bit more information here are the passwd line for the user:

```
client:x:1001:1001:Client,,,:/home/client:/bin/rbash
```

so the user i created is "client" he has no power to `chmod` and my admin user has no power to `chmod` any files of the client's home directory `/home/client/`

here are the files in the `/home/client/`

```
drwxr-xr-x 4 root   root   4096 Feb 26 10:18 ..
-rw------- 1 client client  879 Feb 26 11:42 .bash_history
-rw-r--r-- 1 client client 3523 Feb 26 10:18 .bashrc
-rw-r--r-- 1 client client 3523 Feb 26 11:45 .bashrc~
-rw------- 1 client client  865 Feb 26 11:46 .viminfo
```

To give a scenario:
I created that clent user and affected it to a group. That group was supposed to be restricted to a folder in `/var/www/ClientFolder` but when i logged in to client, i could move around the files and see the codes of my projects. So i followed a solution on stack:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21498667/how-to-limit-user-commands-in-linux

And i found myself with a `home/client/` being only usable by the client. but the latter has no permission. so i now have a folder that cannot be deleted or changed in permission...

thanks again, i hope it's clear

Comment: can you please show us the output of passwd file, group file
by running cat /etc/passwd cat /etc/group from root user or any sudoers using sudo before the command it would be appreciated if you can describe the whole scenario with usernames and directories so we can guide you easily also the permissions that you find on directories and files that are inaccessible by root user getfacl your_directory_name_here/ getfacl your_file_name_here or use ls -l

Comment: `rbash` is a restricted bash that would more or less serve you purpose, you should change home dir from `/home/client` to `/var/www/ClientFolder`. You might still be unable  to view/edit file under `/var/www/ClientFolder/sub-folder1` however. if `client` is not expected to run unix commands you are looking for a **chroot**, if not setup of rbash need some adjustement.

Comment: It doesn't matter if nobody has permission to the directory; root is *always* allowed.